# Property view not found, when trying to create button from class file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've created buttons in the view controller using the scripting below. But I want to create lots of the same buttons on different pages, so I want to create my own custom class. But the line where I add subview won't let me access my view. Any advice?

```
- (void)makeButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title atPositionIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    const CGFloat buttonHeight = 60.0f;
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.0f, buttonHeight*index, 300.0f, buttonHeight)];

    button.tag = index;
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Dynamic number of lines
    button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change method call to:

```
 - (void)makeButtonWithTitle:(NSString*)title atPositionIndex:(NSInteger)index view2add:(UIView*)view2add
```

and then in the end of method: `[view2add addSubview:button];`